# Excel - Resize a column in all Worksheets

Tags: excel

I have 52 Sheets in a Excel Workbook (1 for each week). They all have the exact same table, but different values (cash flow). Now, as the number lengths in the cells vary, in all sheets, all the Column widths are different. So for instance:

```
Sheet1, column A width = 100 pixels
Sheet2, columb A width = 105 pixels

Sheet1, column B width = 150 pixels
Sheet2, column B width = 135 pixels ... so on
```

What I want to achieve it make all the columns in all the worksheets the exact same width and height. But this must be based on the largest value for that column from all the sheets combined, not just that sheet.

I am able to *select* all the Sheets, but the next steps is what I'm stuck on. What can I do to resize a particular column, or all columns at once, to a width so it displays the largest value from all the sheets combined. So for instance:

```
Sheet1, column A - based on its largest value, requires width of 120 pixels
Sheet2, column A - based on its largest value, requires width of 140 pixels
Sheet3, column A - based on its largest value, requires width of 100 pixels
```

I want to resize all the Column A's of all 52 Sheets to 140 pixels.

The purpose is that this way, when they are printed, all 52 sheets will host indentically sized tables.

Can this be done automatically in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how many columns you'll be working with, then adapt the following:

```
For c = 1 To 20 '20 columns
  m = 0 'max width reset
  For Each w In Worksheets
    If w.columns(c).ColumnWidth > m Then _
      m = w.columns(c).ColumnWidth
  Next w
  For Each w In Worksheets
    w.columns(c).ColumnWidth = m
  Next w
Next
```

To set up a macro, press Alt-F11, then **Insert**, then **Module**. You can paste this code into the module, then press F5 to run the Macro. Save your work before testing!

Comment: Just one question. Can I exclude any particular sheets? I have a Summary sheet at the end which is completely different to the other 52 and I don't want this to be included in the resizing.

Comment: Sure, an If-Then statement in the 2nd For-Next loop would take care of this. So, at the beginning of `w.columns(c).ColumnWidth = m` you would put `If w.Name <> "Summary" Then `. Keeping this in one line keeps you from having to put the `End If` statement.

Comment: You forgot to put the `_` after `Then`, it flagged as an error, I added the `_` by looking at the first `If` statement lol. I'm new to VB scripting

Answer (score 1):

Could be achieved without a macro by finding all the existing required column widths (`=Cell("width",A1)` etc), consolidating to find the MAX for each column and then grouping and adjusting widths to suit.

Comment: That was my Plan B lol but isn't that unnecessarily long? Finding the Width for each column for all 52 sheets, and then for each Column, manually apply using Select All Sheets method. It works but just really long I suppose :)

Answer (score -1):

If you're not afraid of macros you can do something like this:

```
For Each ws As WorkSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Columns.AutoFit
Next ws
```

Comment: Im not sure how to set up macros, i've never done it before. I use Excel 2013. Any steps?

Comment: There are plenty of resources on the Internet for starting with macros, do a quick search.

Comment: -1 @Rafael, this will not make the columns the same across all worksheets. The tables will not be identical across all 52 sheets.